# PHP error. result not showing as required

Tags: php, web

I am following some video tutorials. but whenever i run the code it doesnt show the form.it prints the code on chrome.
code is under.

```
   <?php
   require('config.php')
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])
   ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action='regiser.php' method='POST'>
   Name:<input type ='text' name='Name' placeholder='Name'><br>
   Username:<input type ='text' name='Username' placeholder='Username'><br>
   Password:<input type ='password' name='Password' placeholder='Password'>            <br>
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Register'>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: you have not ended the required line of code with ; and in if condition not properly closed the parantheses.

Comment: what you want to do actually i have gave you code which will shows the form and on submit it will redirect to regiser.php ..so if you want to do some code of submit event you have to put php code in regiser.php page

Comment: i am not understanding you answer sirr...

Comment: what actually want to perform using ph code just describe the requirement. bcoz first you need to spent some time to be familiar with the mostly used php function, you can't move on until you don't interpret php code in mind..

Comment: @Waqas Aamer
Copy the output and add it to the question, does it shows entire code? If it shows php code which means you are using <? instead of <?php in your config.php file or the web server is not running.

Answer (score 1):

This line has an error:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])
```

A closing bracket is missing.

Depending on how you look at it either your isset function, or your if statement, is missing a closing bracket.

Answer (score -1):

replace php code with

```
<?php
   require('config.php');
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   }
   ?>
```

Comment: i have writtn this also

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

There must be some error in your config.php which you have included in your file using require.. Check your error logs or enable display errors in your php ini and restart your server.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure, but could it have to do with this:

```
<form action='regiser.php' method='POST'>
```

I'm guessing there could be a spelling issue here? Is the correct location of the document used for this form possibly **register.php**??

Make sure you weed out spelling errors before assuming the code methods are incorrect.  Computers aren't telepathic (yet)... they don't know what words you *meant* to type.

Comment: Please share more details. How should such a spelling issue prevent the form from being rendered?